# android studio how to set string Id

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I want to set ID for a dynamically added textview in a loop. I found out that the only function they have is setId with int parameter. How can we set the ID with string, perhaps like this:

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    textView.setText("Text Number "+i);
    textView.setId("@+id/myTextView"+i); // => Is this possible? This will cause error because setId needs INT type parameter.

    linearLayout.addView(textView);
}
```

I don't want to use resource file because it's not dynamic. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot set id with `char` or `string`. Only `int` will work. 
However you can use the `setTag()` API. You can later do `getTag()` or use `findViewWithTag`

Comment: I use findViewWithTag but it said Cannot Resolve Symbol findViewWithTag

Answer (score 0):

No, You can't. Only `int` will work.

This link may help you for details understanding. https://stackoverflow.com/a/30253770/4365240